# Can't run JUnit tests in Play Framework and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, playframework

I'm trying to run some JUnit tests for my Play framework project but when I run a test I get the following error message:

```
Class not found ApplicationTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ApplicationTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I found this question and I tried some of the suggestions but nothing helped: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228047/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-junit)